# CMD prompt window pops up and instantly disappears periodically

Tags: cmd.exe, virus, malware, prompt

Windows 10 - Every 10 minutes or so, a command line window flashes on my computer. I'm afraid I may have been infected by something. I've been staring at the Task Manager (and process explorer) for days, and can't narrow it down to what is causing this. I've tried MSconfig to check the startup programs- nothing seems out of the ordinary. I've used Malwarebytes, and ran Tron Script once, and installed all the new windows updates, in hopes it would fix the problem, but it still persists.

I may have downloaded something.

Is there a way to check the Event Viewer to see what is launching this window?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Check the task scheduler, see if anything added in there could be triggering it.

Answer (score 40):

I think it's fixed! I checked the Task Scheduler, like NetServOps said, and found one line item that was scheduled to run every 10 minutes. "Firefox Default Browser Agent A99BB431EF49E2C3". I disabled it and have not had the flash of the cmd prompt since! Thank you so much.

Comment: Note that proper way to disable it would be through [firefox settings](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/what-is-firefox-default-browser-agent). it seems to be firefox telemetry data collector.

Comment: Well look at that. I figured it would be a virus (and it may still be) but Firefox really does that: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/toolkit/mozapps/defaultagent/default-browser-agent/index.html

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue a few years ago, and I found the culprit using the Sysinternals tool **Process Monitor**.

1. Download [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).
2. Filter/Filter/Operation is "Process Create"/Add
3. Leave Process Monitor running until it happens again.
4. Check the window:

[image: screenshot of Process Monitor output]

Comment: I just thought you linked to a fake version of Procmon, but they really updated the UI. Wow

Comment: When you find the process, you can use `Tools`=>`Process Tree` to see what created the process.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. After update windows system (win 11), opening CMD will quickly crashed and disappeared, while Powershell works well.

This is how I fix the issue:

1. Press `Win+R` to open the Run prompt.
2. Type **regedit** > press the Enter button > click the **Yes** button.
3. Navigate to this path: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`
4. Right-click on the **Autorun** String value and select **Delete**.
5. Click on the **Yes** button.
6. Reboot the machine and the issue is gone.

I guess the root cause is that the update of Windows system add some broken autorun that breaks CMD. Hope they fix the issue in the latest update.

Refer: [Fix Process exited with code 1 error in Windows Terminal, PowerShell or CMD](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/process-exited-with-code-1)